# How to send or save my cookie in the frontend when using HTTP

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, frontend, backend

How do I send or save my `cookie` in frontend when sending request from http in `MERN` stack? It is saving in my backend when I use `postman`, so why it is not saving my request in the frontend?